# Java, How to split String with shifting

Tags: java, regex, string, split

How can I split a string by `2` characters with `shifting`.
For example;

My string is = `todayiscold`

My target is: `"to","od","da","ay","yi","is","sc","co","ol","ld"`

but with this code:

```
Arrays.toString("todayiscold".split("(?<=\\G.{2})")));
```

I get: `"to","da","yi","co","ld"

anybody helps?

Comment: String.split will split at specific points.  These strings cannot overlap by definition.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
        String e = "example";
        for (int i = 0; i < e.length() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(e.substring(i, i+2));
        }
```

Comment: @Jason I agree but efficient solution usually more complex, here I propose simple and easy to understand solution. This question is not about performance at all.

Comment: No, I don't agree. You should think about performance where it does meter. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming" ([Donald Knuth](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth))

Comment: Second-most misunderstood quote in the history of programming.

Comment: "this solution grabs every character `n` times" - Not true, this doesn't actually grab any characters at all. When using `substring` the `char[]` backing the `String` is shared between it and the new `String` that is created. The new `String` simply uses a different start and end position, so no characters actually get copied at all.

Comment: @Syon actually that's not fully true either :) It was implemented in such way in <= Java 6. In Java 7 they [changed implementation](http://www.javaadvent.com/2012/12/changes-to-stringsubstring-in-java-7.html).

Comment: @NKukhar: Good catch. Now _I_ stand corrected. I checked the JDK7 source, just not a recent enough version.

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop:

```
String test = "abcdefgh";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < test.length() - 1; i++)
{
   list.add(test.substring(i, i + 2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following regex based code should work:

```
String str = "todayiscold";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\G..)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
int start = 0;
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find(start)) {
    matches.add(str.substring(m.end()-2, m.end()));
    start = m.end()-1;
}
System.out.println("Matches => " + matches);
```

**Trick is to use `end()-1` from last match in the `find()` method.**

**Output:**

```
Matches => [to, od, da, ay, yi, is, sc, co, ol, ld]
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant use `split` in this case because all split does is find place to split and brake your string in this place, so you cant make same character appear in two parts.

Instead you can use Pattern/Matcher mechanisms like

```
String test = "todayiscold";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=(..))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while(m.find())
    list.add(m.group(1));
```

or even better iterate over your Atring characters and create substrings like in D-Rock's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17999399/1393766)